# how to call assign dynamically a python method to a C pointer function exported from a shared library

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I want to solve the following problem. Some C code in a shared library will call a pointer function which is a exported symbol of the shared libary

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*pCallBack)(const char *);

pCallBack one_pointer;

void errorPrint(const char * str)
{
   printf("my address = %p", one_pointer);
   fflush(stdout);
   (*one_pointer)(str);
}
```

let's compile that library as a shared library

```
gcc -fPIC -g -shared -o  call_back.so call_back.c
```

And now I want call it from Python, redefining dynamically the implementation of the `pCallBack` pointer

```
import ctypes
import sys

def myCallBack(str):
    print("inside python" % str)
    sys.stdout.flush()

libcallback = ctypes.CDLL("./call_back.so")
pointer_CallBack = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
libcallback.one_pointer = pointer_CallBack(myCallBack)
libcallback.errorPrint(b"one_string")
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the exported data one pointer could not be redefined. I also try `in_dll` function from `ctypes` but it does not solve the problem

When a try to run my Python script , I get the following

```
LD_PRELOAD="./call_back.so" python3 error.py
my address = (nil)[1]    2871869 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Anyone knows that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Using *ct.in_dll* to modify variables inside the *.dll* works for simple types (*int*). I am not aware how to (cleanly) do that for (function) pointers. As a consequence, you need a new function that simply sets the callback.

There are also some errors:

- No *NULL* check in *errorPrint*
- *argtypes* and *restype* not set for exported function. More details on [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)
- Callback function returning *void* (not *void**)

Here's a working example.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

typedef void (*CallbackFuncPtr)(const char*);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void setCallback(CallbackFuncPtr cb);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void errorPrint(const char *str);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


CallbackFuncPtr callback = NULL;


void setCallback(CallbackFuncPtr cb) {
    callback = cb;
}

void errorPrint(const char * str) {
    printf("C - Callback: %p\n", callback);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (callback) {
        (*callback)(str);
    }
    printf("C - done\n");
}
```

*code00.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.so"

CallBackType = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.c_char_p)


def callback_func(s):
    print("PY - callback arg: {:}".format(s))
    sys.stdout.flush()


def main(*argv):
    dll00 = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    setCallback = dll00.setCallback
    setCallback.argtypes = (CallBackType,)
    setCallback.restype = None
    errorPrint = dll00.errorPrint
    errorPrint.argtypes = (ct.c_char_p,)
    errorPrint.restype = None

    cb = CallBackType.in_dll(dll00, "callback")
    print("Original callback: {:}".format(cb))

    callback = CallBackType(callback_func)
    print("New callback: {:}\n".format(callback))

    errorPrint(b"Before setting callback")
    setCallback(callback)
    errorPrint(b"After setting callback")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q067079630]> ~/sopr.sh
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -shared -fPIC -o dll00.so dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python code00.py
> Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0] 64bit on linux
>
> Original callback: <CFunctionType object at 0x7f07ef740ac0>
> New callback: <CFunctionType object at 0x7f07ef740e80>
>
> C - Callback: (nil)
> C - done
> C - Callback: 0x7f07efffc010
> PY - callback arg: b'After setting callback'
> C - done
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot : it solved my problem. I was not thinking it was also necessary to write a function setting explicitely the callback. Nice!